# javax.servlet.ServletException: Session Object Internals: id : overflowed-session

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I have a Portlet deployed on IBM Websphere Portal server and at busy times when I have a lot of users the Portal server is showing "this portlet is unavailable" when you hit it's Url.

In the logs the following exception is showing...

ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Could not invoke the service() method on servlet MyCystomPortlet. Exception thrown : javax.servlet.ServletException: 
Session Object Internals: 
id : overflowed-session

After doing some research on google I believe what is happening us that there are too many concurrent sessions. First of all can someone give me confirmation that this understanding is correct?

Secondly I believe there are settings in Websphere you can make around this. Maximum in memory session count. At the moment it's set to 1000. I would like to just increase it to 1500 but I am unsure of how to work out if this is too high and hence will risk the server falling over . Can someone please give me advice on this?

Lastly is reducing session timeouts in my portlet another effective way to try and fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortening shorter timeout will help if users are abandoning sessions without logging out, but its usually better to shorten it from default 30 min.

You can increase maximum sessions held in memory but you should also increase maximum heap size then. But make sure your operating system has enough memory resources to handle increased heap, because otherwise if system starts to swap you will have very poor performance.

So try to change that only for failing application (you can override session settings per application), do not change global settings in web container as they apply to all applications by default.

Comment: Gas, thanks for your answer. The thing with my application is that there is no log in and log out. So I never invalidate the session. So the only way the session is cleared is on timeout. If I wanted to how would I set the maximum in memory session count in the web.xml file.

Comment: @Richie In `web.xml` you can only set timeout. Session count you can only set via web admin console in the application server.

Comment: Gas The problem is though I don't think it's valid to have a session timeout in a web.xml for a jsr 169 portlet is it? I'm asking bc i tried it and it didn't seem to work. Then reading on forums some ppl are saying it doesn't make sense to have a session timeout for a single portlet on a page because a portlet is only a widget on a page. If you have an understanding of this it would help me greatly if you could confirm or correct me in my understanding

Comment: Also another question on your previous comment. How would you change the setting only for that application in the web admin console? At the moment in the Websphere console we have the Websphere_Portal server/instance running and all applications and modules in portal inherit their settings from that instance. So how would you separate out settings for the different portlets. Thanks

Comment: @Richie You cannot set it by portlet. You can set it for whole portlet application - all portlets contained in that application. You can find that application in Enterprise applications, if you deployed just `war` via protal web gui, it probably will be prefixed with `PA_xxx`

Comment: Gas when looking in my websphere admin console there are a number of name_PA applications but none of them seem to be running. The only ones I have shows as running are DefaultApplication,PlantsByWebSphere,SamplesGallery,query, ivtApp. Based on this would I be right in saying the one I'm looking for is DefaultApplication? Also I'm wondering what the difference would be if I set it for the DefaultApplication at the Enterprise Application level vs setting is at the WebSphere_Portal instance at the Servers level.

Comment: @Richie - you are logged in to the console on the wrong server (server1 instead of WebSphere_portal). You have to start WebSphere_Portal and log to the console there..

Comment: thanks Gas I'm now in the portal admin console and looking at Porltet Management. Under Portal Management there is Web Modules, Applications, and Porlets. I've checked under those three menus and there doesn't see be be anything like PA_*. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate

Comment: @Richie - you didnt understand me ;-). You should  access normal websphere admin console but via ports on WebSphere_Portal, not through portal admin console (it is for different purposes). But you can change the settings even via server1 console, even if the application looks stopped. It looks stopped as it is running on the different server. After you change the settings and save you will have to restart Portal.

Comment: @Richie most of the portlet applications will be prefixed with PA, so you have to find the rest of the name that matches your war filename. It is really hard to tell more without looking at the console and knowing name of your application and how you deployed it.

Comment: Ok thanks Gas. Appreciate your answer and also the follow up